# Backbone.js: Fetching and getting attributes

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views

I am new to backbone.js and I'm stuck with a simple task.
I want to fetch a record from a Database and put it into a model. The fetching seems to work, but I can't get the model attributes.
Here my code:

My Model:

```
window.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({

url: "mobile-rest/get-anzeige",

initialize:function () {

  },
});
```

My View:

```
window.Page = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize:function () {
    this.template = _.template(tpl.get('page'));
},

render:function (eventName) {
    var self = this;
    this.getRecord(function(resp){
        $(self.el).append(self.template({model: self.model}));
        console.log(self.model);       //works and I see the right values in the console
        console.log(self.model.title);  //is undefined
        console.log(self.model.get('title');  //also undefined 
    });


    return this;
},

getRecord: function(callback){
    this.model= new Model({id: this.id});
    this.model.fetch({data: $.param({id: this.id}), success: callback()});
}


});
```

So the fetching seems to work, but how can I access the attributes?

Comment: What is this.anzeige called from getRecord? I can't see it defined anywhere. You should call really be calling this.model's fetch method

Comment: Can you share what values you see in line `console.log(self.model);`. I agree with the comment above, the value you fetch is not being stored in `self.model` since you are not calling `model.fetch()` method.

Comment: When you say that the console.log works, you mean that you see the model logged as an Object, and that this object has a property called `attributes` and this attributes has a property called `title`?

Comment: you're right, it should be model.fetch() but this was only a typo...
The problem remains the same. 

I could make it work now by changing "callback()" to "callback"
It seems that th callback function with brackets was not executed as callback.

Comment: It shouldn't be `callback()`, it should be `callback` without brackets.

Comment: The `success` callback takes 2 parameters, try passing 2 parameters `console.log`ging that and see what happens. I had the same issue and solved it that way

Comment: @ilse2005 If you've solved the problem, would you mind posting the solution here as an answer?

Comment: I still don't get it. How can I pass parameters to the callback function?

I also tried to run this with cordova.js but there the callback function is not executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make it work now by changing "callback()" to "callback"

Comment: I still don't get it. How can I pass parameters to the callback function? I also tried to run this with cordova.js but there the callback function is not executed.